# Procurve Switch Multiple Gateways

Tags: cisco, routing, hp, vlan, hp-procurve

I have a Procurve 3500yl switch that is currently handling all of the VLANs and the default gateway for my network. Currently, the gateway is set to our old FreeBSD firewall/router and I am trying to switch the traffic to our new Cisco router. I want to run a few tests first, preferably on a test VLAN first, and then one of the user VLANs after.

My question is, what is the best way to force just one VLAN to use the new gateway? I'm new to Procurve switches, so I'm not quite used to all of the little differences.

```
VLAN 11: 10.10.11.0/24
VLAN 12: 10.10.12.0/24
VLAN 13: 10.10.13.0/24
VLAN 14: 10.10.14.0/24
VLAN 15: 10.10.15.0/24
VLAN 20: 10.10.20.0/24 (Test VLAN)

Old gateway: 10.10.11.253
New Gateway: 10.10.9.1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is your new Firewall in a different subnet than the current one?

Comment: You should try accepting answers for some of the other questions you have asked as you have not accepted any so far.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into policy based routing, or, routing based on source addresses.  Typically, routers (or things that route) will only look at the destination of a packet and then send it on its way.  You would need to override that behavior, based on the policy that is set.  Unfortunately, it does not appear that the procurve is capable of doing that.